# Динамический блок на сайте

Tags: html, css, laravel

Есть блок с картой и есть зеленая панель, на которой отображается информация при клике на метку на карте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда метка не выбрана - зеленое поле пустое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу скрывать его, когда метка на карте не выбрана и чтобы оно раскрывалось, когда я кликну по метке.

Вот часть кода, где реализован вывод информации при клике по метке:

```
                <!-- festival description -->
            <div class="col-sm-88">
                <div class="header-section__container">
                    <div id="festival_description" class="festival_description"></div>

                    <script type="text/template" id="festival_description_template">

                        <h3><%= festival_name %></h3>

                        <h4><%= start_date %> - <%= end_date %></h4>
            <h4>
                                    <i>Headliners: </i> <%= headliners %>
                                </h4>
                                <h5>
                                    <i>Description: </i> <%= description %>
                                </h5>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-88">
                                <p>
                                    <i>Headliners: </i> <%= headliners %>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <i>Description: </i> <%= description %>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <%= description %>
                                </p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </script>

                </div>
                <a id="button-close" class="close-details-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" href="" style="display: none"></a>
                <a id="button-more-details" class="more-details-link" href="" style="display: none">More details</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это зеленое поле - фон элемента .header-section. Этот элемент содержит и карту и выводимую при нажатии информацию.